# Is there a way to add a role to a member as soon as the role is created? (Discord.js v12)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was trying to create a new role and add it to a member when running a command once, but it seems that I have to run the command twice (once: for the role to get created, twice: for the role to get added to the member).

I guess this would be due to this error: `TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not an Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.`

```
if (command === 'test') {
  if (!message.mentions.users.size) {
    return message.reply('You need to tag a user!');
  }
  const member = message.mentions.members.first();
  const testRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'TestRole');

  if (!testRole) {
    message.guild.roles.create ({
      data: {
        name: 'TestRole',
        color: 'RANDOM',
      },
    }).catch(() => {
      message.reply('Unable to create role');
    });
  }
  member.roles.add(testRole).catch((error) => {console.log(error);});
}
```

Would there be a workaround for this in order to add the role to the member as soon as it is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `roles.create` returns a promise, you can use `.then()` to add the role to the member

```js
if (command === 'test') {
  if (!message.mentions.users.size) {
    return message.reply('You need to tag a user!');
  }
  const member = message.mentions.members.first();
  const testRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'TestRole');

  if (!testRole) {
    message.guild.roles.create ({
      data: {
        name: 'TestRole',
        color: 'RANDOM',
      },
    })
    .then((role) => {
      member.roles.add(testRole)
    })
    .catch(() => {
      message.reply('Unable to create role');
    });
  } else {
    member.roles.add(testRole).catch((error) => {console.log(error);});
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, however, the error of `TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not an Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.` is still present, is there some solution for this?

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know if the error persists.